# IF condition summation true false for specified column google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As i'm trying to use **IF** condition to **update** on some column not single row but multiple. 
Here is a screen shot for it
[sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oImI2.png). Now as i want a formula something like this way that `=(IF{C2:C}={D2:D},TRUE,FALSE)` for all **I** column of **SELL** and `=(IF{C2:C}={E2:E},TRUE,FALSE)` for all **H** column of **BUY**.
As the sheet is updated from share market every time so it needs to update every time for **true** and **false** against **BUY** and **SELL**.
Any hint would be helpful for the total summation check using IF condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(C2:C),"",C2:C=D2:D))` which ever is same number it gives `TRUE` else `FALSE` same goes for another column `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(C2:C),"",C2:C=E2:E))`

**OR**

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="","",C2:C=D2:D))` for sell & `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="","",C2:C=E2:E))` for buy

Both works the same way

Comment: Thank you @Shiva

Comment: Please remember that as per Stackoverflow guidelines if an answer addresses your question,  accept it and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.